# Проблема с True и False в списках python

Tags: python, алгоритм, сортировка, list

Моя проблема заключается вот в чем:

Список нужно отсортировать таким образом, что бы все ноли в итоге находились в конце списка. Очередность других элементов списка не должна затрагиваться. Но если в списке есть False, оно считается за ноль и тоже отправляется в конец списка. От этого и хочу избавиться. К примеру список [0,1,None,2,False,1,0] должен быть отсортирован так - [1,None,2,False,1,0,0]

Мой текущий код :

```
def move_zeros(array):
for i in range (len(array)):
    if array[i] == 0:
        array.remove(array[i])
        array.append(0)
return array
```

Comment: `array.sort(key=lambda x: type(x) is int and x == 0)`

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Answer (score -1):

Если правильно понял задачу, то вот код:

```
for i in range (len(array)):
    if array[i] == 0:
        array.remove(array[i])
        array.append(0)
    elif array[i] is False:
        array.remove(array[i])
        array.append(array[i])
```

Comment: Желаемый результат:  ``[1,None,2,False,1,0,0]``. Результат вашего решения: ``[1, None, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0]``. Не говоря уже о том, что нельзя одновременно идти по списку и изменять его. Могут вылезти разные неприятные вещи.

Comment: Я думал, что ему и требуется False к 0 приравнять. Про изменение списка согласен, но минусовать необязательно было ;)

Comment: Обязательно :) В вопросе есть пример желаемого результата, поэтому надо было как минимум проверить свой код на соответствие ему. К тому же в вопросе и написано, что False тоже считается за ноль и от этого нужно избавиться.

Comment: буду внимательнее, как хорошо, что есть такие бдительные граждане!